# How to convert Pdf file to byte array in php and send?

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen-5.4

I have found pdf to byte array and vice-versa in java,dotnet and python. But i want to convert pdf to byte array in php laravel. I am using "IMUIS" which is accounting software solution and need to sending journal entries from laravel lumen to "IMUIS" for processing.But it gives the error after converting.

> "Foutmelding": "Kan een object van het type System.String niet converteren naar het type System.Byte[]."

In english that means

> "Error message": "Can not convert a System.String object to the System.Byte [] type."

The documentation is given here:

[doc link](http://cswdoc.imuisonline.com/?page_id=382)

Here is the code for it.

```
public function saveJournal($values = '') {
    //echo "adasd";dd();
    $partnerKey = $values->input('Partnerkey');
    $omgevingscode = $values->input('Environmentcode');  
    $file = file_get_contents($values->file('Pdffile'));
    $str = base64_encode($file);
    $options = array(
        \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_URL => env('IMUIS_URL'),
        \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_CLASSMAP => ClassMap::get(),
    );
    $login = new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\ServiceType\Login($options);
    if ($login->Login(new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\StructType\Login($partnerKey, $omgevingscode)) !== false) {
        $sessionid = $login->getResult()->SessionId;
    }

    $array = [
        'BOE' => [
           'JR' => '2018',
           'PN' => '5',
           'DAGB' => 20,
           'REK' => 20032,
           'TEGREK' => '40',
           'FACT' => 0,
           'BTW' => 4,
           'BEDRBOEK' => 123.45,
           'DAT' => '08-05-2018',
           'OPM' => 'Anand testing from wsdl',
           'BEDRBTW' => 21,
           'FACT' => 0,
           'OMSCHR' => 'Testing from wsdl api',
           'BOEKSTUK' => 2018075
        ],
        'DIGDOS' => [
            'FILE' => $str
        ]
    ];

    $journaalpost = ArrayToXml::convert($array, 'NewDataSet');//convert array to xml string

    $create = new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\ServiceType\Create($options);
    if ($create->CreateJournaalpost(new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\StructType\CreateJournaalpost($partnerKey, $omgevingscode, $sessionid, $journaalpost)) !== false) {
        $jsonResponse = $create->getResult();
    } else {
        $jsonResponse = $create->getLastError();
    }
    return $jsonResponse;
}
```

and here is the response as well:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "CreateJournaalpostResult": false,
        "Journaalpost": "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<NewDataSet><BOE><JR>2018</JR><PN>5</PN><DAGB>20</DAGB><REK>20032</REK><TEGREK>40</TEGREK><FACT>0</FACT><BTW>4</BTW><BEDRBOEK>123.45</BEDRBOEK><DAT>08-05-2018</DAT><OPM>Anand testing from wsdl</OPM><BEDRBTW>21</BEDRBTW><OMSCHR>Testing from wsdl api</OMSCHR><BOEKSTUK>2018075</BOEKSTUK></BOE><DIGDOS><FILE>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</FILE></DIGDOS></NewDataSet>\n",
        "Primarykey": null,
        "Foutmelding": "Kan een object van het type System.String niet converteren naar het type System.Byte[]."
    }
}
```

Comment: Its docs in dutch so please convert it to english first by translate page :)

Comment: Something is missing here. The error message you have shown is a C# error message, but your code is all PHP. What system is returning this error?

Comment: Its coming from Api response from "IMUIS"

Comment: Their API must be broken, because you're doing it correctly according to their docs. http://cswdoc.imuisonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/cloudswitch.pdf

Comment: yes, i think it is something broken. But thousands of people using it. How can we solve this error? I didnt find any developer who use IMUIS already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a **"bug"** in the IMUIS software so it cant be possible to link a pdf file from php. Its may be done by Dotnet because its native language and the entire system built by it. Thanks to all of my **SO** friends for your efforts to helps me to find the issue, i have confirmed this information after call support. So in the future no one get stuck (afterall maybe end of 2018) :)

Answer (score 1):

To convert PDF to byte array you will have to read the document using `file_get_contents()` and then parse it by function `unpack()`.

```
<?php
    public function saveJournal($values = '') {
        $partnerKey = $values->input('Partnerkey');
        $omgevingscode = $values->input('Environmentcode');  
        $file = file_get_contents($values->file('Pdffile'));
        $byte_array = unpack("C*",$file);
        $base64_encode = base64_encode(serialize($byte_array));
        $options = array(
            \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_URL => env('IMUIS_URL'),
            \WsdlToPhp\PackageBase\AbstractSoapClientBase::WSDL_CLASSMAP => ClassMap::get(),
        );
        $login = new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\ServiceType\Login($options);
        if ($login->Login(new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\StructType\Login($partnerKey, $omgevingscode)) !== false) {
            $sessionid = $login->getResult()->SessionId;
        }

        $array = [
            'BOE' => [
               'JR' => '2018',
               'PN' => '5',
               'DAGB' => 20,
               'REK' => 20032,
               'TEGREK' => '40',
               'FACT' => 0,
               'BTW' => 4,
               'BEDRBOEK' => 123.45,
               'DAT' => '08-05-2018',
               'OPM' => 'Anand testing from wsdl',
               'BEDRBTW' => 21,
               'FACT' => 0,
               'OMSCHR' => 'Testing from wsdl api',
               'BOEKSTUK' => 2018075
            ],
            'DIGDOS' => [
                'FILE' => $base64_encode 
            ]
        ];

        $journaalpost = ArrayToXml::convert($array, 'NewDataSet');//convert array to xml string

        $create = new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\ServiceType\Create($options);
        if ($create->CreateJournaalpost(new \mysdk\ImuisSDK\StructType\CreateJournaalpost($partnerKey, $omgevingscode, $sessionid, $journaalpost)) !== false) {
            $jsonResponse = $create->getResult();
        } else {
            $jsonResponse = $create->getLastError();
        }
        return $jsonResponse;
    }
?>
```

Comment: so how to convert it to base64 encode() because we cant convert array from base64_encode() only convert string. Do you know that?

Comment: I updated the answer and added the corrected code. Try it. 
There is no need to use the function `base64_encode()` anymore. The function `unpack()` should work.

Comment: {
    "success": false,
    "error": "DOMDocument::loadXML(): StartTag: invalid element name in Entity, line: 2"
}

Comment: base64_encode is needed.Please see the doc.http://cswdoc.imuisonline.com/?page_id=382

Comment: I updated the code in answer. Try get file by `file_get_contents()`, next use `unpack()` for covert to byte array and `base64_encode(serialize($byte_array))` to get encoded array.

Comment: $img_src = 'C:\Users\getpdf.pdf';
        $file = file_get_contents($img_src);
        $byte_array = unpack("C*",$file);
        $data  = serialize($byte_array);
        $str = base64_encode($data);

Comment: The error now is "An internal error has occurred when creating the journal entry. Please contact MOUSE Software
"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `WsdlToPhp` has constructed client code which is sending the PDF entity as a `String`, when it needs to be a `byte[]`.

So I think the problem may be in code that is not shown here.

Can you take a look at the code generated by `WsdlToPhp` and see if you have any flexibility in how the `$journaalpost` is serialized to see if you can fix in there?

Comment: I dont think so rich bcoz i have sent in simple php as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convert the Base64 string back to text.
var byteString = atob(data.reportBase64Bytes);

// Convert that text into a byte array.
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}

// Blob for saving.
var blob = new Blob([ia], { type: "application/pdf" });

// Tell the browser to save as report.pdf.
saveAs(blob, "report.pdf");

// Alternatively, you could redirect to the blob to open it in the browser.
//document.location.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Its a jquery stuff and i want it on php.